# Запрос avg в модели laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли каким то образом в модели возврачать avg или count в Laravel

Вот моя модель

```
class Task extends Model
```

{

```
use HasFactory;


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class); //'user_id', 'id'
}

public function theme(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Theme::class); //,'user_id', 'id'
}

public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'task_id', 'id');
}
public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'task_id', 'id');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class );//'App\Models\Comment', 'task_id', 'id'
}

public function raitings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Raiting::class);
}

public function avgRaitings() {
    return $this->raitings()->avg('mark');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag','tag_tasks');
}

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'condition',
    'theme_id',
];
```

}

```
 $lastTask = Task::with('user','theme','raitings','avgRaitings')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

А вот запрос в котором я хочу получить средний рэйтинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Laravel 8 есть такая штука [Laravel Eloquent withMin(), withMax() and withAvg()](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eloquent-withmin-withmax-and-withavg-exampleexample.html):

```
 $categories = Category::select("id", "name")
                        ->withAvg('products', 'price')
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
 
        dd($categories);
```